# Mongo DB aggregate grouping multiple values that belong to the same document

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, grouping, aggregate-functions

I have documents that look like this

```
{
"_id": "5e3334cede31d9555e38dbee",
"time": 400,
"datetime": "2020-01-05T16:35:42.315Z",
"version": "2.0.30",
"hostname": "bvasilchik-lt.extron.com",
"testfile": "cards.txt",
"tests": 5,
"failures": 3,
"skips": 0,
"status": "Failed",
"__v": 0
}
```

I want to create a result that includes the documents that have the highest number of time per testfile name, so if the top 10 were all the same **testfile** name I'd only want to show the top one that had the same testfile name.

I have done this but I also wanted to include another field that also shows the number of tests matching that grouping, but the only ways I found were to add the $first or the $last or the $max or the $min for the tests field, but that wouldn't be correct b/c the highest time might have a different number of tests.

I am also matching results from a specific date range

```
const times = await Suite.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            datetime: { "$gte": dateRange.startDate, "$lt": dateRange.endDate, }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: "$testfile",
            time: { "$max" : "$time" },
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            time: order
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            _id: 0,
            testfile: "$_id",
            time: "$time"
        }
    }
])
```

this produces these results

```
[
    {
    "testfile": "lists.txt",
    "time": 900
    },
    {
    "testfile": "buttons.txt",
    "time": 800
    },
    {
    "testfile": "cards.txt",
    "time": 400
    },
    {
    "testfile": "popover.txt",
    "time": 300
    },
    {
    "testfile": "about-pages.neb",
    "time": 76
    }
]
```

but what I want it to return is

```
[
    {
    "testfile": "lists.txt",
    "tests": 5, 
    "time": 900
    },
    {
    "testfile": "buttons.txt",
    "tests": 4,
    "time": 800
    },
    {
    "testfile": "cards.txt",
    "tests": 8,
    "time": 400
    },
    {
    "testfile": "popover.txt",
    "tests": 1,
    "time": 300
    },
    {
    "testfile": "about-pages.neb",
    "tests": 2,
    "time": 76
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add extra field into `$group` and `$project` stages.

You need to use `$max` operator for `time` field and accumulate`tests` field `time:tests` values. In the last stage, we `$reduce` `tests` field taking highest value

```
{
  "$group": {
    _id: "$testfile",
    time: {
      $max: "$time"
    },
    tests: {
      "$push": {
        time: "$time",
        tests: "$tests"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "$sort": {
    time: 1
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    _id: 0,
    testfile: "$_id",
    time: "$time",
    tests: {
      $reduce: {
        input: "$tests",
        initialValue: 0,
        in: {
          $add: [
            "$$value",
            {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$time",
                        "$$this.time"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $gt: [
                        "$$this.tests",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $subtract: [
                    "$$this.tests",
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jDnoPxjiiNI)

Comment: I had originally tried that but ran into the issue where the testfile with the highest time might not have the highest amount of tests, reason being is the test was edited now it has less or more tests than prior. I want to know the test file with the highest time and know how many tests were in that testfile here is an example with more data https://mongoplayground.net/p/1n7v8U1UmmO the test with the time "time": 76.404574 has 4 tests but the query results in 5 tests since that was the max that the testfile about-pages.neb has

Comment: @BarretV check again please, I've updated my answer

Comment: I tried it on the mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/mhIU5lvD5lC

and it still shows up about-pages.neb having a time of 76.404574 which is the correct highest time, but if you look at the document that has that time it only has 4 for tests, but the aggregate shows tests with the value of 5. I guess it's hard to find the document that had the matching time and grab the value of the test from that for the aggregation

Comment: Thank you very much, this was definitely way more advanced than my current MongoDB knowledge so your help is greatly appreciated. That seemed to work and I played around with the data to make sure if I added more it would still be correct just to double check and everything was good

Comment: @BarretV Cool. Good luck